# Expresso Store - mark order as a gift

Tags: expresso-store

Is there any way to pass additional info with Expresso Store order? I would like to have a check box during the checkout process which will indicate to make that order as a gift (requires special wrapping), something similar to `accept_terms` tag.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Custom Order Fields to achieve this. Something as basic as:

```
{field:custom_order1}
```

would create a text input but you can do:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="custom_order1" />Is this a gift?
```

would allow you to create a checkbox. [Full documentation](https://exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html#custom_order_fields) on custom order fields.